Most general conditions for $f(x) = \frac{1}{2}x^TAx$ to be convex
Let $f(x) = \frac{1}{2}x^TAx,$ where $A = \begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{bmatrix} \in \mathbb{R}^{2 \times 2}.$ I wish to determine the most general conditions on $a, b, c, d$ such that $f$ is convex.
So far, I have determined that $f \in C^2(\mathbb{R}^2),$ with Hessian $H = \frac{1}{2}(A+A^T)$. By the $C^2$ characterisation of convexity, $f$ is convex iff $H \succeq 0$. Moreover, by definition, $H \succeq 0$ iff its eigenvalues are positive, i.e.,
\begin{align} \lambda_{+} > \lambda_{-} = \frac{(a+d)}{2} - \sqrt{\left(\frac{b+c}{2}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{a-d}{2}\right)^2} \geq 0, \tag{1} \end{align}
which may be further algebraically simplified. Is guaranteeing condition (1), that $\lambda_{-} \geq 0$, indeed the most general condition on $a, b, c, d$ to ensure $f$ is convex?

I'm not quite sure I understand your question. You seem to know you've found a necessary and sufficient condition for the convexity of $f$. Any other equivalent condition must be equivalent to this inequality. How could a condition get more general?

$x^TAx=x^TSx$ where $S=\frac{1}{2}(A+A^T)$ is symmetric and can be writen $U^TDU$ where $U$ is orthogonal and $D=\mathrm{diag}(d_1,d_2)$. Therefore $x\mapsto x^TAx$ is convex if and only if $y\mapsto d_1y_1^2+d_2y_2^2$ is convex (doing $y=Ux$), if and only if $d_1$ and $d_2$ are $\geq 0$, if and only if $d_1+d_2\geq 0$ and $d_1d_2\geq 0$, if and only if trace $S$ and $\det S$ are $\geq 0$, if and only if $a+d$ and $ad-\frac{1}{4}(b+c)^2$ are $\geq 0$, if and only if $a,d,$ and $ad-\frac{1}{4}(b+c)^2$ are $\geq 0$, etc.
